# SOLR index size reduction

Tags: optimization, memory, solr, indexing

We have a some massive SOLR indices for a large project, and its consuming above 50 GB of space .

We have considered several ways to reduce the size that are related to changing the content in the indices, but I am curious of wether or not there might be any changes we can make to a SOLR index which will reduce its size by 2 orders of magnitude or more, which are directly related to either (1) maintainance commands we can run or (2) simple configuration parameters which may not be set right.

Another relevant question is (3) Is there a way to trade index size for performance inside of SOLR, and if so , how would it work  ?

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated... Thanks!

Comment: It will help if you can post your `schema.xml` and some sample documents.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a couple things you might be able to do to trade performance for index size. For example, an integer (int) field uses less space than a trie integer (tint), but range queries will be slower when using an int.

To make major reductions in your index, you will almost certainly need to look more closely at the fields you are using.

- Are you using a lot of stored fields? If so, try removing the stored fields from the index and query your database for the necessary data once you've got the results back from Solr.
- Add omitNorms="true" to text fields that don't need length normalization
- Add omitPositions="true" to text fields that don't require phrase matching
- Special fields, like NGrams, can take up a lot of space
- Are you removing stop words from text fields?

Comment: Thanks - are any of these "order of magnitude" differences ?  From the look of it, they seem like they might only change things by a small percentage.... We need a massive reduction (and we're not doing anything crazy like huge text indices... most fields are small... but we just have alot of them).

Comment: Omitting norms and positions could save a lot of space, especially with the size of your index. Take a look at this article: http://css.dzone.com/news/solr-index-size-analysis

Comment: +1 I'd also add that term vectors use a lot of space, and if you have a lot of segments, then doing some merging could help share data between segments