# Tune solr phrase query search

Tags: search, solr, datastax, datastax-enterprise

We are trying to tune our phrase queries in DSE search. 
For example, if we have column name X with the value "D A T A S T A X" we are searching for exact match for X:"T A S T"

Words are tokenized with with whitespacetokenizer.

We have couple hundred Million records in database and all the indexes are memory (We tested using pcstat). However still the queries are taking 5-15 sec. Why it is taking so time to pull the results if all the indexes are in memory? How can I tune this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The value "D A T A S T A X" contains the white space between chars. The real data also contains the same? Because the whitespacetokenizer will split this into individual chars. One more thing, are you search for substrings with exact match, this substring could be of variable lenght. Can you also provide the details of filterCache, queryCache and documentCache from your solrconfig.xml?

Comment: Yes you are right am searching for exact substring and real data contains the same pattern with white spaces between characters. The substring can be any length. <filterCache class="solr.SolrFilterCache" highWaterMarkMB="256" lowWaterMarkMB="128"/>, <documentCache class="solr.LRUCache" size="512" initialSize="512" autowarmCount="0"/>. We do not want to depend on cache because our queries are not repeated. We want our queries perform well on the first run.

Comment: As your data is tokenized by WhitespaceTokenizer. The query and index phase will break the word into individual characters given the nature of data. Please check this: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory

Comment: Other way could be, You tokenize the data with Keyword Tokenizer because it pass the same word to filters. Then apply Edge N-Gram filter with max and min gram size. Can you please tell more about the data?

Comment: Yeah I understand that. That is the reason am searching for a exact substring. If am doing it wrong the how to search a exact substring in my case?? I already tried edgengram and ngram. They did not helped me much.

Comment: Can you please tell more about the data?

Comment: We have data with numbers and characters seperated by white spaces. We tried edge ngrams with this data which did not performed well and we tried to remove white spaces and applied edgengram filter and queried the data with pre and post wild cards and it did not performed well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Try this fieldType:

```
<fieldType name="custom_edge_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([^A-Za-z0-9])" replacement="" replace="all"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([^A-Za-z0-9])" replacement="" replace="all"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Here the KeywordTokenizerFactory tokenizeer will pass the text stream exactly to the filters. The PatternReplaceFilterFactory will remove all except characters and numbers. You can config this however you want. Then we lowercase the stream and generate the NGram. This is for the index phase. For the query phase we don't do the NGram because we want to match the exact sub string.

We will be use the NGram instead of EdgeNGram, Because that will provides substring. The EdgeNGram always contain either from start or end. So EdgeNGram is not helpful in this case.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How to run the query? X:"*TAST*" or X:"TAST". Does generating edgengrams from back is useful then front?

Comment: What solr version are you using? The EdgeNGramFilterFactory have different behavior in solr 4 and solr 5.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will test it. How to run the query? X:"TAST" or X:"TAST"

Comment: You can query anything. X:"TAST" or X:"T A S T". both will work. because we are replacing all the whitespace with empty. I have tested in solr analysis tool. Try the same.

Comment: Now the query response time came down to 1-2sec but our index sizes are almost dounbled and just for 180G of data we have 120G of index size. I saw your other post to reduce the index size but still we have large index with ngrams. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32009475/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-a-generated-lucene-solr-index/32010329#32010329

Comment: What is the minGramSize and maxGramSize values are you using? You can optimize the index size by optimal values for these parameters. It completely depends on your query and data. Because the small value for minGramSize we generate a lot of indexes which are not required in real time scenario.

Comment: Am using min 3 and max 10...our field can have up to 15-20 characters.

Comment: You can perform term analysis using TermComponent. Use this: http://localhost:8983/solr/<core>/terms?terms.fl=<field>&terms.limit=10&wt=json&indent=true. May be you want to remove some of the words from getting indexed using StopwordFilter.

Comment: I added omitNorms="true" termVectors="false" termPositions="false" termOffsets="false" but still my index size did not reduced. is there anything else I can do to reduce the index size?