# Can Lucene.net search from zipped directory

Tags: lucene.net

i have indexed my text files with lucene.net FSDirectory and compressed the indexed Directory with winzip.

now i want to search a pattern from the directory. is there any way in Lucene.net to search from zipped index directory?

Comment: The Lucene.NET index is already heavily compressed.  Did using winzip on the index save much space?

Comment: example:  using winzip compresses from 495kb to 272 kb

Comment: This might be helpful: [How to use HIGH_COMPRESSION in Lucene.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65834288).

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box I don't think there is a way to do that.  However you could perhaps create your own extension to Lucene.NET that supports that by unzipping parts of the index on the fly as it's loaded into memory.

But even if it could be implemented, searching such an index is likely to be super slow.

And it's unclear that such an approach can be implemented since lucene needs to be able to access precise offsets into files and you'd have to be able to decompress parts of the zip file at that equivalent offset without decompressing the whole file. So that sounds pretty challenging.  There is even a fair chance that it's not possible.

Comment: It is possible to do an in-memory decompression of the file (like was done with [LineFileDocs](https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/blob/a7c6477db41904a71f2ed4eb198830344de1fb32/src/Lucene.Net.TestFramework/Util/LineFileDocs.cs#L147-L155) in prior betas). This works well in Java because it is highly optimized to use `.jar` files, which are zip files  with another name. However, in .NET this is extremely slow, which is why we now unzip the file to a temp directory and work with that.

Comment: @NightOwl888 That's a cool example for situations where memory is large enough to load the whole unzipped index. However, if the index doesn't fit in memory I suspect searching a zipped index without first unzipping it to disk would be vary hard to implement for the reasons I mentioned.